# Is it possible to disable the listener of one slide direction of flutter_slidable?

Tags: flutter

I'm using a slidable inside a drawer but it overrides the drawer's listener so it makes closing the drawer by sliding it not possible. Is there a way around it? I only want the slider to open one direction and close the drawer for the opposite direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but you can try like that:

```dart
IgnorePointer(
    ignoring: true,
    child: SlidableWidget(), // Change this
);
```